# How to calculate how much GPU power to mine 1 coin a day for any cryptocurrency?

Tags: gpu-mining, hashrate, hashrate-comparison

I am trying to apply the system of equation explained in [this link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/how-much-cpu-power-to-mine-1-coin-a-day), but these equation are specific for monero, how can I calculate the gpu power for any cryptocurrency? this mean, how can I know the values of the constants used in this system of equations (e.g. how they now the value of M is M = 2^64, the constant 10^(-12), etc)

I know you can calculate this with https://www.cryptocompare.com but I want to know the equations they use.

Do these equations change if the cryptocurrency if different than monero?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be the following:

`Daily mining estimate = ((your hashrate) / (network hashrate)) * (current block reward) * (number of blocks in a day)`